# Change seaborn pair plot figure size

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
sns.pairplot(data=train, 
              x_vars=['x'],
              y_vars=['y'])
plt.show()
```

and I am programming in Jupyter notebook, if that makes any difference. I want to plot a much larger figure of the plot, but I cannot do it. I searched the internet and the documentation mention to use the height property
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html
but that always results in an error for me when using the following code.

```
sns.pairplot(data=train, height=3,
              x_vars=['x'],
              y_vars=['y'])
plt.show()
```

`TypeError: pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'height'`

Comment: It looks like you are using an old version of seaborn which does not have the `height` argument. Is it an option to update seaborn or are you asking for a solution for your version? (In this case please specify which version that is.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you for your answer, I just run this
`conda install -c anaconda seaborn`
but it did not fix my issue

Comment: Which version of seaborn are you using???

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  `>>> import seaborn
>>> seaborn.__version__
'0.8.1'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `height` parameter is available in seaborn 0.9.0.

```
sns.pairplot(..., height=3)
```

In seaborn 0.8.1 (or lower) this parameter was named `size`.

```
sns.pairplot(..., size=3)
```